# Is it possible to disable specific XML attributes from a custom view in Android?

Tags: android, listview, scrollbars, xml-attribute, custom-widgets

I'm creating my own personalized ListView by extending the `ListView` itself. This particular ListView shouldn't have scrollbars.

1. How can I disable the XML `android:scrollbars` attribute for my custom `ListView`?
2. I can't find a way to disable them programmatically. What am I missing?

The answer from dzeikei's will disable the scrollbars programmatically and ignore any value from `android:scrollbars` but what I'm really asking on 1. is how to make `android:scrollbars` an invalid attribute for **my** custom component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**
OK as Richardo found out, seems like my original answer is the reverse way since the scrollbar is displayed internally :)

The correct way will be to call 
`super.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false)` and `super.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false)` in the constructor and override `setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled()` and `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled()` do nothing :D

> Override `isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled()` and
>   `isVerticalScrollBarEnabled()` in your subclass to return `false`.
>
> you could also override `setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled()` and
>   `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled()` for good measure.

Comment: Thanks for that. But my main question is about the XML attribute thing as specified by the question title. Just to be clear, I know that overriding those methods will do the trick, but what I'm asking is if there's a way to make `android:scrollbars` invalid for my custom component. Maybe I should clear that up in the question...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `<declare-styleable>` works similar to method declaration, you cannot undeclare something in the subclass. You are welcome to prove me wrong though :)

Comment: I just tested your suggestion and overriding both `isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled()` and `isVerticalScrollBarEnabled()` to return false didn't do anything, the scrollbars still show. I actually had to call the `set` methods on the constructor and set them to false. But to prevent them from being set to true I need to override the `set` methods and always set them to false. Please update your answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping @null for android:scrollbars. Am not sure. But, I usually use @null when i want to remove anything from XML attributes.

Comment: am sorry, I thought of the normal ListView with customized Adapter.